# Useful vector space with dimension $n^n$ over the reals.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I am looking for a reasonable vector space with dimension $n^n$ over the reals. The motivation comes from the following problem:

> Suppose $k > n^n.$ Define $f(X)$ as the product of the elements along the diagonal of $X.$ If $A_1, B_1, \dots, A_k, B_k$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $f(A_i B_j) = 0$ for all $1 \le i \ne j \le k,$ show that there exists $i$ such that $f(A_i B_i) = 0.$

What vector space should I consider in order to solve the problem? How could you come up with this space if you didn't already know about it? All the common sense vector spaces I could concoct have dimension $n$ or $n^2,$ but not $n^n.$

Comment: What are $A_i$ and $B_j$ in this problem?

Comment: @peek-a-boo $n \times n$ matrices. Question has been updated.

Comment: What do you mean by reasonable? Any $n^n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ is going to be isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n^n}$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Yes, but some isomorphisms are more useful than others. I don't see a way to work with $\mathbb{R}^{n^n}$ directly.